# Bootcamp Windows Partition Won't Boot After Accidentally Changing Boot-up Partition

Tags: macos, bootcamp, windows, partition

I was messing around with the startup partition on my Windows 7 partition on my Mac and accidentally changed it to the Mac OS X partition. So when I boot the Windows 7 partition it says the error message "Missing Operating System". This error also shows up when I try to boot the Windows 7 DVD from the Mac drive selector screen. My question is how do change the boot partition on my Windows 7 partition if the partition won't even boot? I really don't want to install a new Windows 7 partition.

**Mac Specifications:**
Type: *Mac Pro (Mid 2012)*
Processor: *3.33 GHz 6-Core Intel Xeon*
Memory: *32 GB 1333 MHz DDR3 ECC*
Graphics: *ATI Radeon HD 5770 1024 MB*
Software: *OS X 10.8.4 (12E55)*

Comment: Hi and welcome to Apple.SE. Could you please edit you question such that it actually contains a question? I can see what you want to do (boot into Windows 7 again), but it is better when you state it yourself such that people don't have to guess.

Comment: Thanks for correcting me. I edited the description and added the question that I'm seeking.

Comment: So you press and hold Option while the system is booting, you then select the Windows 7 DVD, what happens exactly? It goes straight to a screen stating "Missing Operating System"?